# pattern: swift callbacks with gcd

Tags: design-patterns, swift, callback, grand-central-dispatch

I have an async function that has to report back to the caller on its own private queue. Rather than add several queues and closures to my function definition, I figured to use a encapsulating struct
So that this:

```
func doStuff(input : String, progressQeue : dispatch_queue_t, completionQueue :dispatch_queue_t, progress : ()->(), completion : ()->())
```

becomes this:

```
func doStuff(input : String, dispatch : Dispatch?)
```

with:

```
struct Dispatch<ProgressionType,CompletionType>
{
    var progressQueue       : dispatch_queue_t
    var completionQueue     : dispatch_queue_t
    var progression : ProgressionType //a closure
    var completion  : CompletionType //a closure


    //dispatch with gcd
    func complete_sync(input : ()->())
    {
        dispatch_sync(completionQueue) {
            input()
        }
    }

    func complete_async(input : ()->())
    {
        dispatch_async(completionQueue) {
            input()
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

You can call the dispatch from within the function like this:

```
func doStuff(input : String, dispatch : Dispatch<()->(),()->(String,Int)>?)
{
  //do work
  ...
  //callback
  dispatch?.complete_async{dispatch!.completion("a", 3) }
}
```

Advantage: 
you hide the queues and callback functions behind one optional parameter

Disadvantages: 
the Dispatch<> definition can get rather long
the dispatch syntax is a bit weird. It would be better to have something like this:

```
  dispatch?.complete_async("a", 3)
```

But I don't know how to pass these parameters to the completion function within the struct. A variadic parameter could work if the generic CompletionType would accept parameters

```
func complete_async(parameters : AnyObject...)
{
    dispatch_async(completionQueue) {
        completion( ??? )
    }
}
```

If you have any feedback on this approach, it's more than welcome.

**Edit:**
I just realised that a callback closure will always have a void return:

```
(...) -> ()
```

So this becomes possible:

```
struct Dispatch< CompletionType > {
   var function : (CompletionType -> ())?

   init()
   {
   }

   func complete_async(parameters : T)
   {
      dispatch_async(completionQueue) {
        completion(parameters)
      }
   }
}
```

called as:

```
 dispatch?.complete_async( ("pi", 3.14) )
```

The only restriction here is that CompletionType is a tuple, for example: (String,Double)

Comment: I left out a few variables and functions in the edit, but it's easy to combine it with the pre-edit code

Comment: I think you can greatly simplify the problem when you let the call-site define where to execute the actual handlers (e.g. using `dispatch_async` and friends), and just pass two closures to the `doStuff` function which calls back on a private queue of its choosing.